# Glob function on windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, glob

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>


#include <opencv\cvaux.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>



using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

#define NCLUSTERS 35

// Build a BMB comprising of nclusters number of background models from training images
// in pathfolder. BMB[0] = centroids estimated by Kmeans and BMB[1] = standard deviations

void BuildBMB(const String pathfolder, const int nclusters, vector<Mat> &BMB){

    Mat ycrcb, rgb, vect, Data, labels;
    vector<String> files;

    // filenames of training images


       glob(pathfolder, files);



    // Compute Data = rgb & ycrcb of training  images
    for (unsigned  int i=0; i< files.size(); i++){
        // Read RGB the image files[i]
         fprintf(stdout, "Read image %d/%d\n", i, (int)files.size());
         rgb = imread(files[i]);
         imshow("RGB image", rgb);
         waitKey(10);

         // Convert from uchar -> float and scale between [0,1]
         rgb.convertTo(rgb, CV_32FC3, 1.0/255.0);

         // Convert for color space RGB to color space YcrCb
         cvtColor(rgb, ycrcb, CV_BGR2YCrCb);

         // Reshape  to LIGNE vectors
          rgb = rgb.reshape(1, 1);
          ycrcb = ycrcb.reshape(1, 1);

         // Concatenation of rgb & ycrcb
         hconcat(rgb, ycrcb, vect);

         // Insert  vect to Data
         Data.push_back(vect);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "Data [%d,%d] is computed.\n", Data.rows,  Data.cols);
    // clustering Data by kmeans
    fprintf(stdout, "Compute Kmeans...\n");
    kmeans(Data, nclusters, labels, TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER|CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 350, 1e-3), 3, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, BMB[0]);

    fprintf(stdout, "centroids [%d,%d] and labels [%d,%d] are computed.\n", BMB[0].rows,  BMB[0].cols, labels.rows, labels.cols);
    double minl,maxl;
    minMaxLoc(labels, &minl, &maxl);
    fprintf(stdout,"labels : min=%f, max=%f\n", minl, maxl);

    // Compute BMB[1] of standatd devaiations. BMB[1] has the same size of BMB[0]

}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    // Train the Background models BMB based on kmeans
    fprintf(stdout, "Start training ....\n");
    vector<Mat> BMB(2, Mat());
    String pathfolder = "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\image\\trainning\\*.jpg";
    BuildBMB(pathfolder, NCLUSTERS, BMB);
    fprintf(stdout, "End of training.\n");

    return(1);
}
```

the problem here is that I use windows and fuction glob does not exist.(linux function)
how do I use glob on windows ?
Or do I need another function to load the images names into "files"
I think that i can use " cl typeit.c /link setargv.obj " but coudn't fiugre it out.

Comment: You should use [cv::glob](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26536198/5008845)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ as i said i don't know how to use setargv.obj , i already saw that post ...

Comment: @Miki thanks but glob doesn't work on windows, it's a linux fuction

Comment: `cv::glob` **does** work on Windows (I use it daily). This is an OpenCV function (note the namespace `cv::`), not a linux function!

Comment: Have a look also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32550727/5008845)

Comment: the problem is, that you're including the wrong opencv header files. `opencv\cv.h` and all those are from the arcane c-api, which is dead and gone. to get the cv::glob functionality, replace all of them with: `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`