# reading multiple files in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

i tried below code to read the multiple images from a folder

```
VideoCapture cap("/home/image%3d.jpg");
while( cap.isOpened() )
{

    Mat frame;
    cap.read(frame);

}
```

But it's throwing error as,

```
Image step is wrong () in cvSetData, file /build/opencv-iepTEA/opencv-2.4.9+dfsg/modules/core/src/array.cpp,
line 928terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /build/opencv-iepTEA/opencv- 2.4.9+dfsg/modules/core/src/array.cpp:928: 
error: (-13)  in function cvSetData
```

Comment: can you post some filenames of images in your folder?

Comment: for me, `cv::VideoCapture cap("path/%5d.jpg");` works if the files are named `00000.jpg`, `00001.jpg`, `00002.jpg`, and so on

Comment: @Micka image000, image001

Comment: Have a look also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32550727/5008845)