# How to process images from a folder for an opencv algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv

I need to process many images from a certain folder with my opencv algorithm, but i don't know how.
The steps would need to be like this:

1. Read and process the first image;
2. After processing it, take this image off this folder and put it into a "processed images" folder. The results would be saved in another folder. Each image would have to have a name like "img001, img002" and so on.
3. Repeat everything until the main folder is empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading an ordered sequence of images in a folder using OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550620/reading-an-ordered-sequence-of-images-in-a-folder-using-opencv)

Comment: Please refer to the accepted answer of the question pointed by @Miki. With some tweaking, you should be able to work out how to save images, too.

Answer (score 1):

For list of files look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c). Moving files or deleting it is more complex problem as there is no simple solution (is OS dependent) but you can use [boost::filesystem::rename](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#rename) and [boost::filesystem::remove](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#remove) or [std::rename](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rename/) and [std::remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/remove/).